# Как обновить аргументы функции?

Tags: javascript

Есть код JS:

```js
    function Villager(count) {
      setInterval(() => {   
        veg = veg + (count * 0.02);
        fruit = fruit + (count * 0.02);
        berr = berr + (count * 0.02);

        document.getElementById('veg-num').innerHTML = veg.toFixed(3);
        document.getElementById('veg-num-r').innerHTML = veg.toFixed(3);
        document.getElementById('fruit-num').innerHTML = fruit.toFixed(3);
        document.getElementById('fruit-num-r').innerHTML = fruit.toFixed(3);
        document.getElementById('berr-num').innerHTML = berr.toFixed(3);
        document.getElementById('berr-num-r').innerHTML = berr.toFixed(3);
      }, 5000); 
    }

//остальной код...

function buyVillager() {
    if(money >= 20) {
      VillagerCount = VillagerCount + 1;
      Villager(VillagerCount);
      console.log(VillagerCount);
    }
    else {
      alert("У вас недостаточно монет...");
    }
  }
```

Второй блок запускается по нажатии на кнопку в html и уже он запускает первый блок кода. И если нажать эту кнопку еще раз, то первая функция просто запуститься еще раз.

Нужно что бы вызывалась только последняя вызванная функция, а "старая её версия - удалялась". Или просто старая версия обновляла свои аргументы. Это возможно реализовать?

Если нужно - залью на jsfiddle(только я не знаю как делиться кодом там...).

Пробовал прерывать функцию так:

```js
var stopVill = false;

function Villager(count) {
        if(stopVill === false) {
            setInterval(() => { 
                veg = veg + (count * 0.02);
                fruit = fruit + (count * 0.02);
                berr = berr + (count * 0.02);

                document.getElementById('veg-num').innerHTML = veg.toFixed(3);
                document.getElementById('veg-num-r').innerHTML = veg.toFixed(3);
                document.getElementById('fruit-num').innerHTML = fruit.toFixed(3);
                document.getElementById('fruit-num-r').innerHTML = fruit.toFixed(3);
                document.getElementById('berr-num').innerHTML = berr.toFixed(3);
                document.getElementById('berr-num-r').innerHTML = berr.toFixed(3);
            }, 5000);
        }
        else {
            stopVill = true;
            return false;
        }
    }

//остальной код

function buyVillager() {
        if(money >= 20) {
            VillagerCount = VillagerCount + 1;
            stopVill = true; 
            Villager(VillagerCount);
            stopVill = false;
            Villager(VillagerCount);
            console.log(VillagerCount);
        }
        else {
            alert("У вас недостаточно монет...");
        }
    }
```

Пробовал

````
function Villager(count) {
        var VillagerJob = setInterval(() => {   
            veg = veg + (count * 0.02);
            fruit = fruit + (count * 0.02);
            berr = berr + (count * 0.02);

            document.getElementById('veg-num').innerHTML = veg.toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById('veg-num-r').innerHTML = veg.toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById('fruit-num').innerHTML = fruit.toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById('fruit-num-r').innerHTML = fruit.toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById('berr-num').innerHTML = berr.toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById('berr-num-r').innerHTML = berr.toFixed(3);
        }, 5000);
    }

//остальной код...

function buyVillager() {
        if(money >= 20) {
            clearInterval(Villager.VillagerJob)
            VillagerCount = VillagerCount + 1;
            Villager(VillagerCount);
            console.log(VillagerCount);
        }
        else {
            alert("У вас недостаточно монет...");
        }
    }
```.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Villager(count) {
  return setInterval(() => {   
    ...
  }, 5000); 
}

var timer;
function buyVillager() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  if(money >= 20) {
    VillagerCount = VillagerCount + 1;
    timer = Villager(VillagerCount);
    ...
}
```

Comment: А как работает clearInterval? Вы же не занесли сам setInterval в переменную? Просто интересно.

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: но вы же просто объявили пустую переменную и очистили у нее интервал :|

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn Функция `clearInterval` ничего не делает, если в нее передается переменная, которой не соответствует ни один интервал, запущенный в данный момент.

Comment: но вы же так и сделали.... Я пробовал помещать ```setInterval``` в переменную и ```clearInterval``` для этой переменной, но всё равно не работает...

Comment: на хабре писали сделать так: >Чтобы "обновить аргументы", достаточно замкнуть функцию в каком либо пространстве, убрать у неё аргументы и использовать значения из контекста выше, тогда callback переданный в setInterval будет всегда получать "актуальные" данные. Или же, тебе нужно куда-то записывать ссылку на интервал и использовать WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.clearInterval() при повторных кликах.    Но всё равно не работает...

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn "Я пробовал помещать ..." - Я должен догадаться, как выглядит код, которым Вы пробовали?

Comment: исправил вопрос...

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn Ваша `var VillagerJob` - локальная переменная внутри функции `Villager`, которая снаружи не видна.

Comment: опечатался... Исправил. Теперь так, как было, когда я пробовал...

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn `Villager.VillagerJob` - это Вы сами придумали? Такой конструкции в JavaScript-е нет.

Comment: нет. Видел в ролике на ютубе. Так так обращались к переменной внутри функции. Я просто еще новичок в js и не все понимаю..

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn Хорошо. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: если ваш ответ мне не помог, зачем мне ставить галочку?

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn Мой ответ Вам помог.

Comment: чем он мне помог? У меня ничего не заработало...

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: покажите, где, как?

Comment: сильно извиняюсь. Не дописал одну букву....